# Perl - Returning the maximum value in a data set

Tags: perl, pdl

I have never delved into the world of Perl before and I find it pretty confusing and could use some help. In the code below the calc() section returns a running average of an'input' over 'count' samples. I would like to modify that so the calc() returns the maximum value within the sample set. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
sub calc
{
    my ($this, $dim, $input, $count) = @_;

    if ($count < 1)
    {
        warn "count=$count is less than 1.";
        return undef;
    }

    my $inputsum_in = $this->{inputsum};
    my ($inputcumsum, $inputsum_out) = PDL::CumulativeSumOver2($input, $inputsum_in);

    my $inputdelay = $this->delay('inputhistory', $input);
    my $inputdelaysum_in = $this->{inputdelaysum};
    my ($inputdelaycumsum, $inputdelaysum_out) = PDL::CumulativeSumOver2($inputdelay, $inputdelaysum_in);

    $this->{inputsum} = $inputsum_out;
    $this->{inputdelaysum} = $inputdelaysum_out;

    my $sampleno = $this->{sampleno};
    my $divider = $count;
    if($sampleno < $count)
    {
        my $last = $dim - 1;
        $divider = sequence($dim) + ($sampleno + 1);
        my $start = $count - $sampleno;
        $divider->slice("$start:$last") .= $count if $start <= $last;
        $this->{sampleno} = $sampleno + $dim;
    }
    return ($inputcumsum - $inputdelaycumsum) / $divider;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback already. In the above code the '$input' is from a sensor that is being read every 100ms so for however many samples ('$count') I choose to look at the max value returned. I would think return max($data_set); would be work fine. I just don't know how to generate the data_set from the '$input'. The data set needs to constantly update with the new inputs while the oldest data is dropped. The perl interpreter is built into automotive diagnostic software so the method above calc() is how it needs to be done.

Comment: Well, I'm out of my element with PDL. I assumed there would be a max() function and googled it. But as for creating piddles from data, I'd just end up reading the PDL docs for you.

Comment: The "max" method works on any PDL object. If you "use PDL", max is also a function imported into your current package. It looks like whoever wrote your code knew a thing or two about PDL, and the best place to get answers for PDL is to join the Perldl mailing list: http://mailman.jach.hawaii.edu/mailman/listinfo/perldl

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
 $max = max($input);
```

[PDL Primitives](http://llama.mshri.on.ca/~fgibbons/lib/pdl/Primitive.html#max)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the maximum of a certain list of values, you do not need to write your own subroutine. There is already a function that comes shipped with perl v5.7.3 or higher:

```
use List::Util qw(max); # core module since v5.7.3
use strict;
use warnings;

print max(1 .. 10);  # prints 10
```

Comment: His code already uses PDL. So $input is very likely going to be a "piddle" rather than a list/array.

Comment: in my experience, `List::Util` and `PDL` don't play nicely together.  PDL defines `max` and `min`, so `use`ing the `List::Util` versions of max and min causes the interpreter to refuse to run your script.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Here is the loop I take it you need.

1. Read input data from sensor
2. append new data to stored data
3. Throw away excess data
4. Evaluate

Here's how I'd do it.

```
my $storedData = pdl;  
# $storedData is now a vector containing one element, 0
while (! stopCondition()) {
    my $input = readSensorData(); # step 1
    $storedData = $storedData->append($input); # step 2
    if ($storedData->nelem > $count) { # step 3
        $storedData = $storedData->slice("-$count:-1");
        # note that -1 points to the last element in a piddle and -X refers to 
        # the element X-1  away from the end (true for piddles and native arrays)
    }
    my ($max, $min) = evaluate($storedData); # step 4
}
```

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but your comment below seems pretty different from the question you have above.  Consider editing the above to better reflect what you're having trouble with or asking a new question.

---

An easy way to get a running average is with a finite impulse response filter, aka convolution.  Convolve any signal with a (normalized) rectangular impulse and you get running average.

```
my $filter = ones($count) / $count; 
my $runningAve = convolveND($input, $filter); 
my $max = $runningAve->max`;
```

Or in one line

```
my $max = convolveND($input, ones($count) / $count)->max;
```

`convolveND` [is documented here](http://pdl.perl.org/PDLdocs/ImageND.html#convolvend).

---

There is one thing to be careful of with this method, which is that the values at the beginning and end of the $runningAve piddle aren't really running averages.  To ensure that the output is the same size as the input `convolveND` (by default) effectively concatenates zeroes to the beginning and end of the input, the result being that the first and last few elements of `$runningAve` are lower than actual running averages.  (Note that a running average should have `N - (window - 1)` elements in principle, N being the size of `$input`.)  Since these "bad" values will necessarily be lower than the actual running average values, they won't disturb the maximum that you want.  (Re "by default": `convolveND` has other ways of handling edges, as you will see in the documentation linked to above.)

(NB: I am not a PDL expert.  There may be a cheaper way to get the running average that's cheaper than convolveND, something like `$ra = $input->range(...)->sumover(0) / $count`, but I don't know what you'd put in the ... and the above is readable.  See also http://search.cpan.org/~jlapeyre/PDL-DSP-Iir-0.002/README.pod#moving_average)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The code example above already calculates the running average. What I need code for is to build a dataset from the 'my ($this, $dim, $input, $count) = @_;' that stores $count # of $input values while deprecating the old values as new $inputs are received. Then from that dataset I can 'return MAX(dataset); or Min as required.

Comment: I don't really follow.  If you only want to consider the recent entries in `$input` you can do any relevant calculations on `$input->slice("-$count:-1")`.  If you want to tack the new stuff on to the old and only leave `$count` elements, then you can say `$store = $old->append($new)->slice("-$count:-1")`.

Comment: You might update your question because it seems like you haven't fully described what you need. (PS backtick \` signifies code formatting.)

Comment: Part of my problem is that I really don't know enough about Perl and how Perl handles data. Does it automatically store the incoming data as an array of some form? Anyway, despite my Perl ineptitude this is what I need (in human), and it needs to follow the structure of the code example in my OP as `sub calc{....}`.

Comment: In diagnostic software user sets $count (must be >0) as the quantity of input values to evaluate.  
While diagnostics are running;  
1. Get $input from sensor
2. Add $input to $all_inputs  
3. If count($all_inputs) > $count  
  3a. Then: store newest of ($all_inputs) in $inputs_to_eval  
  3b. Else: store all of ($all_inputs) in $inputs_to_eval  
4. Evaluate $inputs_to_eval and return either the Min or Max value within the set. I can't even figure out how to properly format this list.....  =/